# Downloading Google Font Meta Data for All Google Fonts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-font-api, google-fonts

I'm looking for a JSON file containing all the Google font names and the weights available for each font.  This is in order to create CSS Utilities like this:

```
u-font-montserrat-fw500 {
    font-family: montserrat !important;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
}
```

Anyone know if Google makes the font meta data available?

Comment: There’s a [public API](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api#details) available.

Comment: Wow - It's really easy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did.  First got a key to the [Google Font API Here](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api#APIKey).

Then I did this:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=A6345634762zPXb2iE_Yoi60 > google-fonts.json
```

The result json file will have all the font weights and fonts listed in it.

```
    {
      "family": "ABeeZee",
      "variants": [
        "regular",
        "italic"
      ],
      "subsets": [
        "latin"
      ],
      "version": "v14",
      "lastModified": "2020-09-02",
      "files": {
        "regular": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abeezee/v14/esDR31xSG-6AGleN6tKukbcHCpE.ttf",
        "italic": "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abeezee/v14/esDT31xSG-6AGleN2tCklZUCGpG-GQ.ttf"
      },
      "category": "sans-serif",
      "kind": "webfonts#webfont"
    },
```